# Simple App crashes when started, programming fault

Tags: android

A simple android program to Enter a text (in `Edittext`) and copy to `clipboard` (after hitting copy button)...

It crashes when opened, what am i missing?

```
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText e1;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                copytext(view);
            }
        });
    }

        public void copytext(View view) {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", (CharSequence) e1);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
        }

}
```

I also tried using below with no success :

```
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", String.valueOf(e1));
```

my xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.quickclip.panky.quickclip.MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="100"
        android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
        android:text="Your Voice Input" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="copytext"
        android:text="Copy" />

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the log cat

```
01-31 15:16:19.168 7127-7127/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
01-31 15:16:19.458 7127-7127/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.quickclip.panky.quickclip-2/lib/arm64
01-31 15:16:19.459 7127-7127/? D/ActivityThread: installProvider: context.getPackageName()=com.quickclip.panky.quickclip
01-31 15:16:19.463 7127-7127/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
01-31 15:16:19.474 7127-7127/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-31 15:16:19.475 7127-7127/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.quickclip.panky.quickclip, PID: 7127
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.quickclip.panky.quickclip/com.quickclip.panky.quickclip.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.quickclip.panky.quickclip.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2536)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2699)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:196)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5857)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1026)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:887)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.quickclip.panky.quickclip.MainActivity> cannot be instantiated
                                                     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2526)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2699) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:196) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5857) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1026) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:887) 
01-31 15:16:19.515 7127-7127/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 7127 SIG: 9
```

I am new to android programming :)

Comment: share your **crash log** and **xml layout** with question

Comment: post your error log

Comment: share your crash log and complete code. The Activity code is also not complete. As you have implemented OnClickLIstener but no where implemented the onClick method, so how can you expect help without sharing complete problem state.

Comment: @Pankaj see the answer i have added

Comment: i am new to android programming, please give me an opportunity to learn by giving helpful feedback :)... my question is being downvoted :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [**`newPlainText`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipData.html#newPlainText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

**Structure**

```
ClipData newPlainText (CharSequence label,CharSequence text)
```

2nd param is **`CharSequence: The actual text in the clip.`**

**Finally**

```
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", e1.getText().toString());
```

**FYI**

- Remove **`abstract`** kEYWORD.

**onCreate section**

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               copyMethod();
            }
        });
    }
```

**And**

```
 public void copytext(View view) 
    {
     copyMethod();
    }  

    public void copyMethod() 
    {
     ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
     ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", (CharSequence) e1.getText().toString());
     clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    }
```

Comment: I have added logcat, thankyou for your quick response

Comment: Thankyou! for helping even if my question was downvoted. Jai Hind

Answer (score 2):

Without any logs, there might be other errors as well, but here is one:

You cannot cast an `EditText`, which is a UI Object, to `CharSequence`. Instead, do it like this:

```
public void copytext(View view) {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copied Text", e1.getText().toString());
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
}
```

Comment: `e1.getText().toString()` not `e1.getText()`

Comment: I have added logcat, thankyou for your quick response

Answer (score 2):

Just remove abstract from activity it will cause `java.lang.InstantiationException:`

**Replace**

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

**with**

And implement

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

Implement interface by Override  onclick method

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
```

Comment: I have added logcat, thankyou for your quick response

Comment: have you overwrite onClick method ?

Comment: it says .. it should either be abstract or implement abstract method onclick(view) or onclicklistener

Comment: i have updated answer,i think you have not implemented onClick method just implement it

Comment: yes you have to implement the method not to make it as abstract